# Eclipse won't boot application. Java classes changed?

Tags: java, eclipse

I just attempted to update an existing project to use Maven dependencies as oppose to existing jars that were stored in `/lib/`. However upon doing so, I found that my class images have changed from:

[image]

And I don't know why, or what the de-coloured `J` means. I haven't encountered this in Eclipse before. Can anyone offer any advice?

All of a sudden my application wont boot because it can't find `main()`.

Comment: I believe that "J" means it is no longer included in your build. I would check out your build paths.

Comment: what happens when you execute mvn build?

Comment: How does your POM look like and what's the project folder layout? Switching to Maven might have made Eclipse look for `.java` sources in the standard Maven locations, if you were using a different layout before that may be why Eclipse can't find your code.

Comment: Hey, you was all right about it no longer being included in the build path. After updating the build path, all seems to be working with the exception of all my @overrides, which is odd as they're still implementing interfaces that need to be overriden.

Comment: Maven defaults to Java 5 level, in which `@Override` is only used for overriding methods, not implementing methods. You should adjust your maven compiler settings (see [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html)).

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks for everything!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The icon means the file is recognised as Java source, but no longer as part of your project. Check the build path (and maybe you need to reload from the POM if it is incorrect).

Comment: Hey, you was right about it no longer being recognised as part of the project. I've included it in the build path again. Thanks!